# Adding Leading Zeros to Multiple Cells in Excel at Once

Tags: excel, vlookup, leading-zero

I have been working on a database which needs VLOOKUP to another database. The lookup table displays values without leading zeros as:

```
5625698
2586585
2479653
9985632
1125478
```

To be specific, I want to convert these numbers to display preceding zeroes. Instead of editing each cell separately and converting it to Text Format, I want to know whether there is a shortcut to add preceding zeroes to multiple cells at once.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at www.extendoffice.com

The solution is to either use the CONCENTRATE function in a different column, which is similar to the suggestion of EEM (but this is not what I was looking for). Or use VBA Module with the following code:

```
Sub AddTextOnLeft()
'Updateby20161004
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim addStr As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Add Text"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
addStr = Application.InputBox("Add text", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = addStr & Rng.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula to add leading zeros and convert the number to text

```
=TEXT(XXX,"00000000")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will help. Considering this formula will help me perform the operation in one cell. I intend to do so to multiple cells at once.

Comment: Didn't you mentioned that the values are obtained with a Vlookup formula. Then place your vlookup formula within the text formula. e.i. =Text(vlookup(x,range,col,0),"00000000")

Comment: No, the values are not obtained with a vlookup formula. Both tables have the values in common, one of them without the zero. When I search for values without zero in the table that has values with zero, the result is #N/A. If I edit the value without a zero and add a leading zero, the result is correctly displayed as required. Instead of editing each cell (around 300 lines in the table to be edited), I want to know if I can edit all the cells at once.

Comment: so you are searching the values without zeros in the table with leading zeros is that correct or it's the opposite? What are you using to perform the search?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. Keeping calculations aside, I just want to convert the text to display preceding zeroes (I have edited the question)

Comment: you could add a working column and use the formula provided.. then have your "search" pointing to the working column...

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do it. Ok I think what you are doing here is that trying to reformat phone numbers which excel being over-smart broke in first place. Anyway you can use following steps

1. Select cells, Right Click, Click Format Cell
   [image]
2. Format Cell dialogue will appear, choose custom from left list and
   type zeroes upto max length e.g. for mobile phone number its ten
   digits in Australia including leading zero.
   [image]
3. press ok. And voila!!
   [image]
4. Bonus: if you like to format you phone numbers with parenthesis ()
   and/or with spaces you can do the same way by adding them in format
   string

[image]